# Evaluting the following integral

Tags: calculus

So I have been trying hard to get this integral in the same form of the answer wolfram alpha gives. How does $$\int \frac{-x^2+2x+y^2-1}{(x^2+y^2-2x+1)^2}\ \mathrm{d}y=-\frac{y}{x^2-2x+y^2+1}+C$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $x^2-2x+1$ is a constant, call it $a^2$, then your integral is
$$\int{y^2-a^2\over (y^2+a^2)^2}dy\ .$$
Use the trigonometric substitution $$y=a\tan\theta\ ,$$ so 
$$y^2+a^2=a^2\sec^2\theta$$ 
and 
$$dy=a\sec^2\theta\ .$$ The integral is now
$$
\begin{align}
\int{a^2(\tan^2\theta-1)\over(a^2\sec^2\theta)^2}a\sec^2\theta d\theta
&=-\frac1a\int(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)d\theta\\
&=-\frac1a\int\cos2\theta\,d\theta\\
&=-\frac1{2a}\sin2\theta\\
&=-\frac1a\sin\theta\cos\theta\\
&=-\frac{a\tan\theta}{a^2\sec^2\theta}\\
&=-{y\over y^2+a^2}
\end{align}
$$
plus constant of integration.